# Necesito ayuda para mantener la información de una columna booleana en un jtable

Tags: java

tengo esta tabla con una columna booleana checkbox para seleccionar un registro 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero si yo selecciono uno [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y meto algo en el buscar y lo selecciono y me devuelvo a mi tabla original [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pierdo los valores que tenia en esa columna [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y no se como hacer para recuperar estos valores, se que es estúpido buscar cuando solo tengo 2 valores pero es solo un ejemplo, puede que tenga 200 registros y es útil buscar y seleccionar pero el problemas es que no se guardan la información de esa columna

aquí están los códigos esos métodos tanto del buscar que esta en un evento como el del mostrar 
El mostrar `public void MostrarVentas() {
        Modelo = (DefaultTableModel) TablaVentas.getModel();
        String SQL = "SELECT cant_exist,nombre,num_parte,precio_unitario,total_ganancia FROM repuesto WHERE estado=? and cant_exist > 0 "
                + "ORDER BY cant_exist ASC";
        try {
            ps = Conexion.prepareStatement(SQL);
            ps.setBoolean(1, true);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            limpiarTablaRepuestos();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Object[] contenido = new Object[Modelo.getColumnCount()];
                contenido[0]=false;
                for (int i = 0; i < Modelo.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    switch (i) {
                        case 1:
                            contenido[1] = String.valueOf((int)rs.getInt(i));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            contenido[2] = rs.getString(i);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            contenido[3] = rs.getString(i);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            contenido[4] = String.valueOf((BigDecimal) rs.getBigDecimal(i));
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            contenido[5] = String.valueOf((BigDecimal) rs.getBigDecimal(i));
                            break;
                    }
                }
                Modelo.addRow(contenido);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error no hay datos" + e);
        }
    }`

y el buscar `public void Buscador() {
        try {
            String filtro = BuscarRespuesto.getText() + "%";
            String SQL = "SELECT cant_exist,nombre,num_parte,precio_unitario,total_ganancia FROM repuesto where "
                    + "(CAST(cant_exist as varchar) like ? OR nombre like ? OR "
                    + " num_parte like ? OR CAST(precio_unitario as varchar) like ? OR CAST(total_ganancia as varchar) "
                    + "like ?) AND estado=? ORDER BY nombre";
            ps = Conexion.prepareStatement(SQL);
            ps.setString(1, filtro);
            ps.setString(2, filtro);
            ps.setString(3, filtro);
            ps.setString(4, filtro);
            ps.setString(5, filtro);
            ps.setBoolean(6, true);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            limpiarTablaRepuestos();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Object[] contenido = new Object[Modelo.getColumnCount()];
                contenido[0] = false;
                for (int i = 1; i < Modelo.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                    switch (i) {
                        case 1:
                            contenido[1] = String.valueOf((int) rs.getInt(i));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            contenido[2] = rs.getString(i);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            contenido[3] = rs.getString(i);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            contenido[4] = String.valueOf((int) rs.getInt(i));
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            contenido[5] = String.valueOf((BigDecimal) rs.getBigDecimal(i));
                            break;
                    }
                }
                Modelo.addRow(contenido);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ventas.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }`
a el buscar lo invoco desde un evento 
`private void BuscarRespuestoKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {

        Buscador();
    }`
intente usando el

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que podrías hacer es crear una clase con los datos del registro, y además agregarle la variable de checkbox, por ejemplo

```
public class Modelo {
private cant;
private registro
....
private boolean check;
```

una vez hecho esto al hacer la consulta los insertas en el objeto y no directamente la tabla, esos objetos los insertas en un `List` o en un `ArrayList`, lo que sea y de ahí llenas tu tabla.
De esta forma el check estará apuntando a una variable que no se destruye al quitar la columna por lo cual al marcarla en búsqueda estará cambiando al objeto, al volver a la tabla el check del objeto sigue marcado.

Si te agrada la idea échale un ojo a Hibernate, que lo que hace es propiamente convertirte las consultas en objetos de clases mapeadas previamente es lo que se conoce como ORM (Object Relation Mapping)

```
tuCheckbox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (tuCheckBox.isSelected()) {
                tuObjeto.setElNombreDeTuBoolean(true);
            } else {
                tuObjeto.setElNombreDeTuBoolean(true);
            }

        }
    });
```

Eso agregarselo a cada checkbox al momento de llenar la tabla

Comment: lleno mi tabla con los datos dentro del arraylist pero los cambios siguen perdiendose

Comment: Agregale al checkbox un evento de que cuando se seleccione se cambie el boolean de tu clase, edito mi respuesta para que veas el codigo más o menos como hacerlo

Comment: okey pero ese checkbox es una columna booleana como hago para seleccionar ese evento?